# Get enum value from smart contract with javascript

Tags: web3js, react

This is my contract:

```
enum State { Active, Refunding, Pending, Releasing}

function state(uint orderid) public view returns (State) {
        return State.Releasing;
    }
```

In one Javascript to interact with contract:

```
async getState(order_id) {
    const contractInstance = await this.contract.deployed()
    //const status = ['Active', 'Refunding', 'Pending', 'Releasing']
    return contractInstance.state.call(order_id);
  }
```

In another javascript to call that function:

```
case RELEASE_PAYMENT:

        console.log("order_id in orderReducer:",action.id);

        (new PaypalContract())
                    .releasePayment(action.id)
                    .then(() => (new PaypalContract()).getState(action.id))
                    .then((e)=> {
                        console.log("status in orderReducer:",e)
                        return{
                          ...state,
                          orderStatus:e
                        }
                    })
        return{
                ...state,
                orderStatus:'Releasing'
              }
```

From web dev tool, I can see the returned 'e' is always a object, not a string value I expected. Any ideas?

Another question is about react, it looks the react just render once with the first returned state, after I got 'e' from contract, it won't render with the updated state.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your `e` is a promise object which you need to resolve in order to get the actual value that you seek to get.

Comment: It has been resolved by .then, the "e" is not a promise, it is another object.

Comment: Well, why don't you print the contents of that object and share them here with the rest of us then?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved:

It returned 'e' as an int object, so I use an array to take 'e' as an index.

```
const sta = ['Active', 'Refunding', 'Pending', 'Releasing'];
        (new PaypalContract())
                    .releasePayment(action.id)
                    .then(() => (new PaypalContract()).getState(action.id))
                    .then(function(e) {
                        console.log("status in orderReducer:",sta[e])
                        return{
                          ...state,
                          orderStatus: sta[e]
                        }
                    })
```

It printed out:

status in orderReducer: Releasing

Answer (score 0):

Hello sir have you figured out a way to do this without maintaining a enum in the frontend? and instead querying a public state variable ?

```
enum CaseStatus {
    CREATED,
    ACTIVE,
    FINAL
}

CaseStatus public caseState = CaseStatus.CREATED;
```

`function getEnumValue() constant returns (uint){return uint(caseState );}`

Hope This Helps